# Implementing DisplayMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, device-detection

I am currently working with mvc 4 and interested in implementing the DisplayModes feature which sniffs the browsers accessing the site and renders an appropriate view based upon the browser/device.

For example, code to check for iphone and render the applicable view:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf
        ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

I have read that out of the box it sniffs for mobile devices, and adds the mobile name to the view.

I want to create a similar, bit for tablets. Has anyone implemented this or instructions of how to do it? I can go check the user agent etc for tablet, but this feature is hit and miss so wondering if this has been achieved by anyone as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such notion as *tablet* in HTTP. There are user agents. Tablets use different user agents. Here's [`a list`](http://mojosunite.com/tablet-user-agent-strings) of some of them. So all you have to do is adapt the code you have shown to match substrings of those user agents against particular devices.

Comment: Thanks will check this out. Just want to confirm in saying that I don't need to do same for mobile as this is in built?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good overview and example available on ASP.Net called [ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features).  Pretty much goes over the entire set of DisplayModes with examples.